# How to update state with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to build simple login form (data for authorization from API). So I have Slice for auth here is code :

**auth.js**

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState: {
        isLoggedIn: false,
        token: null,
        role: null
    },
    reducers: {
        logIn: (state) => {
            state.isLoggedIn = true
        },
        role:(state, action) =>{
            state.role = action.payload
        },
        token:(state, action) =>{
            state.token = action.payload
        },
        logOut: (state) => {
            state.isLoggedIn = false
        },
    },
})

export default authSlice.reducer;



export const { logIn, logOut, role, token } = authSlice.actions
```

**authService.js** :

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { api } from '../api/index'


export function authenticateUser(username, password) {

    axios
        .post(api + 'login', {username, password})
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.headers.authorization)
        })
}
```

**LoginForm.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Col, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { IoMdLogIn } from "react-icons/all";
import { authenticateUser } from '../services/authService'

export default class LoginForm extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.initialState;
        this.credentialsChange = this.credentialsChange.bind(this);
        this.userLogin= this.userLogin.bind(this);

    }


    initialState = {
        username: '', password: ''
    }

    userLogin = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        authenticateUser(this.state.username, this.state.password);
        this.setState( () => this.initialState)
    }

    credentialsChange = e => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]:e.target.value
        });
    }

    render(){


        const {username, password} = this.state;

        return(
          <Form onSubmit={this.userLogin}   id="loginFormId">
              <Form.Row>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridCountry">
                      <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
                      <Form.Control required autoComplete="off"
                                    type="text" name="username"
                                    value={username}
                                    onChange={this.credentialsChange}
                                    className={"bg-light"}
                                    placeholder="Username" />
                  </Form.Group>
              </Form.Row>
              <Form.Row>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridZipCode">
                      <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                      <Form.Control required autoComplete="off"
                                    type="password" name="password"
                                    value={password}
                                    onChange={this.credentialsChange}
                                    className={"bg-light"}
                                    placeholder="Password" />
                  </Form.Group>
              </Form.Row>
              <Button type="submit" variant="success">
                    <IoMdLogIn />
              </Button>
          </Form>
        );
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to reach is : I want to update state isLoggedIn : true after calling function authenticateUser.

I've tried to use `const dispatch = useDispatch()` and then calling `dispatch(logIn())` but it's throwing error.

Where should I call dispatcher to update state?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the dispatcher in your AuthService.js in the api response.
Check the response, if it is ok, store it. If your redux is well implemented, it will work.

```
 axios
        .post(api + 'login', {username, password})
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.headers.authorization)
            //Call it here, or create a function and call it here.

        })
}
```

If it doesn't work, please share the error with us

Comment: Called dispatcher like you said : `const dispatch = useDispatch();`
Then in axios.post `dispatch(token(jwtToken)) dispatch(logIn())`
And this is what i get : 
react-dom.development.js:14906 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: Can you place your code in a git repository? Then we can see exactly what is going on